# How to filter array of strings

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, substring

I'm trying to isolate certain strings in an array, e.g.,

```
["banana man", "apple", "banana woman"]
```

which are identifiable by the start of the string (i.e. substring). I want to keep `'banana man'` and `'banana woman'` but remove `'apple'`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the prefix (e.g. `"banana"`) in advance or do you have to extract / identify it from the given strings?

Comment: Issue is not clear at all. In which way is `"apple"` isolated from the other two elements? Is it because it starts with `"a"`?

Comment: Beth, if  `a` is your array and we interpret your question literally (as we should), `a.delete("apple")` is sufficient (though I doubt that's what you are looking for).

Comment: "[Bananaman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIHEFlD_VDM)" is one word. There's also a [Banana Kid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkJWCI8y66s).

Comment: Issue was that I had a whole bunch of html returned when I curl a URL and all I wanted were the object names inside that mess.

Answer (score 9):

This is a great usecase for `grep`

```
ary = ["banana man", "apple", "banana woman"]
ary.grep(/^banana/) # => ["banana man", "banana woman"]
```

Comment: While `grep` results in a visually simple expression, the benchmark shows it's costly.

Comment: Thanks, this worked brilliantly, performance hasn't been raised as an issue yet for the program so I'll keep using grep.

Answer (score 3):

Try `start_with?` and `select` to choose just those that start with the string you want:

```
["banana man", "apple", "banana woman"].select { |i| i.start_with?("bana") }
=> ["banana man", "banana woman"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Benchmark time:

```
require 'fruity'

ARY = ["banana man", "apple", "banana woman"]

ARY.grep(/^banana/) # => ["banana man", "banana woman"]
ARY.select { |i| i.start_with?("bana") } # => ["banana man", "banana woman"]

compare do
  grep_only { ARY.grep(/^banana/) }
  select_start_with { ARY.select { |i| i.start_with?("bana") } }
end
# >> Running each test 4096 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> select_start_with is faster than grep_only by 3x ± 1.0
```

Extending `ARY`:

```
ARY = ["banana man", "apple", "banana woman"] * 1000

compare do
  grep_only { ARY.grep(/^banana/) }
  select_start_with { ARY.select { |i| i.start_with?("bana") } }
end
# >> Running each test 8 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> select_start_with is faster than grep_only by 3x ± 0.1
```

Comment: Thank you for the benchmarks. it is funny the next fastest method (~ half speed) I can find is actually join and scan (which seems error prone depending on the specifications).

Comment: Then add that into the mix. It's a community wiki for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

At the Tin Mans behest, and due to the fact that your actual specifications are very vague, I will add this alternative solution as a possible but potentially error prone option.

```
ARY = ["banana man", "apple", "banana woman"] 
ARY.join('  ').scan(/banana\s\w+/)
#=> ["banana man", "banana woman"]
```

This will out perform `grep` but is about half the speed of `select` and `start_with?` combination and is based solely on the post and not your potentially underlying intentions.